# PUT Request form body in RESTLet and HTTPClient

Tags: java, jax-rs, httpclient, restlet, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm struggling quite a bit with transporting a form body between the Apache HTTPClient and a JAX-RS service running on RESTLet.

Here's what I do to send the PUT request:

```
HttpPut put = new HttpPut("http://localhost:1337/api/user/default/inventory");
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addTextBody("url", item, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

put.setEntity(builder.build());

HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(put);
```

And my service looks like this:

```
@PUT
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("user/{id}/inventory")
Public Response addResourceToProfile(@FormParam("url") String url, @PathParam(value="id") String userId, @Context HttpHeaders headers){
try {           
    UserProfiles.get(userId).addToInventory(url);

    return Response.ok("{result:\"success\"}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Response.serverError().build();
            }
        }
```

The url parameter allways ends up being **null**...

Answer (score 0):

Why are using multipart encoding to transmit a lone parameter? Besides by the look of it the service actually expects 'form-urlencoded' content. Most likely the request constructed this way should be enough

```
HttpUriRequest put = RequestBuilder.put()
        .setUri("http://localhost:1337/api/user/default/inventory")
        .addParameter("url", item)
        .build();
```

Comment: Because I'll end up adding more parameters later on. And because I needed to simulate whatever a JavaScript based application would be posting with the fewest parsing overhead possible.

Comment: @Michael: nothing stops you from having more parameters in a form-urlencoded request. Most likely from-url encoding is what your java script uses anyway. If you are absolutely sure you need multipart encoding, then your service is wrong